# JENKINS - Is there a way to only update modified files?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have configured the project with Jenkins. When jenkins build starts its taking Svn update then ant build and then stop and start the application.

But In some cases I would like to do only SVN Update. EX : if I have modified only Html content there is no need of ant build and restart. Is ther any way to do that in jenkins? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ant is intended for incremental builds. But, of course, that's up to the tasks that you use, not the Ant engine itself. In many cases, tasks have to wrapped with up-to-date guards to prevent touching files that don't need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the point of doing "only SVN update"? You should probably not execute the job in such cases at all.

In the SCM configuration, you can click the <kbd>Advanced...</kbd> button and configure **Excluded Regions** with `**/*.html`. This would prevent the job from being triggered at all on changes to HTML files only. This only applies to jobs configured with SCM polling.

Answer (score 0):

I just verified that you can poll SVN based on "Advanced" settings of "Include/Exclude" files. Thanks for correcting me Slav.

You can find them here:

[image]